# Ext Google Calendar

Tags: extjs, google-calendar-api

I am trying to implement Google Calendar as per the example of sencha https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/examples/calendar/
But I have a lot of difficulty.
After much trial and error, I get the error finding the class 'Ext.layout.Context' which from what I can see is not supported in Ext Modern (I use modern version 6.7).
Has anyone experienced the same mistake, or would you know a way to solve it?
Or another way to implement Google Calendar?

Comment: Could you please translate your question into English or, alternatively, post it on https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Describe your problem in more detail. If it is possible to add an implementation with an error in fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/)

Comment: In short, I am unable to use this component.
The mistake is when I try to build the project.
I would like to use according to the example site of sensha, but I do not see how.